# Is it legal to kill a scotsman in York?

Tags: law, united-kingdom

I once heard that it is allowed to kill a scotsman in York, if you do it with a bow and arrow. Apparently there is no danger in this law, since the bow and arrow needed to be made by a no longer existing factory.

But is it really true?

Comment: The version I've come across is "In the city of York, it is legal to murder a Scotsman within the ancient city walls, but **only if he is carrying a bow and arrow**". This is quoted on many news sites but a search on the UK Statute Law database does not bring this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is often repeated, but sometimes in reverse: for example this [Guardian article from 2007](http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2007/nov/07/uk.queensspeech20072) states the Scotsman must be holding the bow and arrow.

Unlike the [Welshman in Chester](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/was-it-legal-to-hang-any-welshman-found-in-chester-after-sunset) question, I can't see any acknowledgement by York City Council that there is any historical record of this.  But such instructions have often been given during wars and there were many Anglo-Scottish wars, so it is not impossible; such instructions cease to apply once peace is concluded.

Comment: Instructions given to whom by whom under what authority? Presumably the relevant *law* isn't "You may kill a bow-and-arrow-carrying Scotsman.", but something along the lines of killing a person isn't considered murder/manslaughter if they are an armed enemy combatant during a time of war.

Comment: Somebody carrying a bow and arrow in public and appearing hostile would probably still be considered a threat to be met with potentially lethal force today, no? A real bow and arrow, as romantic and anachronistic as we might see it today, is still a deadly weapon.

Answer (score 21):

This "law" ranked 10th in the search for the [UK's 10 stupidest laws](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1568475/Ten-stupidest-laws-are-named.html) widely reported as the result of a 2007 survey

> 10) In the city of York it is legal to murder a Scotsman within the ancient city walls, but only if he is carrying a bow and arrow (2%)

The source for most of the laws listed on the survey for 10 stupidest laws is this book:  [The Strange Laws of Old England [Hardcover] by Nigel Cawthorne](http://www.amazon.co.uk/reader/0749950366?_encoding=UTF8&query=york&new_account=1#reader_0749950366)  as stated in the [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/7081038.stm)

On page 197 the search results (only preview) show as below

> And in York, it is said, it is perfectly legal to shoot a Scotsman with a bow and arrow ..

[image]

Whats interesting is that a subsequent amended BBC article of the same 'most ludicrous laws' **listed 7 of these and left out this one** with the comment.

> - This is an amended version of an earlier story which included several examples of laws from the survey which we have been unable to
>     verify, and these have been removed.

So in summary, this may or may not have been there once upon a time, but **now seems to be a local legend rather than a stated law**.

It definitely does not appear in the search results of the [UK Statute Law database](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/)

Comment: The authenticity is debatable. I have yet to find any actual quotation of the law. Many such laws are either [phased entirely differently from the way they get restated in "Stupid Law" books or never existed at all other than in legend][1]. The [FOI request to the City of York][2] has yet to find such a law on the books. 


  [1]: http://blogs.phoenixnewtimes.com/valleyfever/2013/09/10_arizona_dumb_laws_that_are.php
  [2]: https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/in_york_it_is_perfectly_legal_to